# Drawable as background of splash theme doesn't keep ratio

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen, scaletype

In my application, I'm trying to set the `splash t`heme with a `drawable background`. It works correctly if I use a *small image*, but when the image is *bigger then the screen size*, it doesn't work anymore.

The image is *correctly scaled horizzontally*, but the `height` isn't, as follows:
[image: my splash]

I tried every scaletype and gravity, what else can I do?

**this is my Theme:**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

**This is my background_splash.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

<item
    android:left="50dp"
    android:right="50dp"
    >
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo_splash"
        android:gravity="center|clip_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />
</item>
```

**and this is my manifest (relevant code):**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `ImageView` with proper `ScaleType` instead of setting background .

Comment: @ADM thanks for replying. it's because if you sett a splash layout instead of a splash theme, when the app starts a white screen is shown for a moment, and after that you will see the layout. By this way, you immediatly see the resource without the white screen

Comment: What is the size of your `@drawable/logo_splash` in pixel?

Comment: @ThomasMary pretty huge: 1050 x 1050. I will reduce it later, but I would love a way to do this anyway

Comment: What if you remove `android:gravity="center|clip_horizontal"` in background_splash.xml ?

Comment: @ThomasMary not working :(

Comment: `android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"` will work for large images

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layer-list like this in your background_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="fill" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/logo_splash"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

This will center your image on the screen and the left space will be filled by the white background color.

Maybe you have to add the image in different sizes like you can read here:
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

If you do that you can access the image with the same name. It will look like this your project structure:

[image]

If you want to remove the action and status bar in your splash screen, you can add the following line to your SplashTheme:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```